# Animation between Activity Transitions like on Android Tinder?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, tinder

I have an Android device with version 4.1.1. Running Tinder App on this device I get a nice transition from on Activity/Fragment to another.

Example:

[image]

I have seen that inAndroid Lollipop there are Activity transitions but they are not available on earlier versions.

Activities are changed with Intents, but when you try out the Tinder app there is an animation when you move from one Activity to another.

**How does Tinder make the transitions between two Activities/Fragments?**

Comment: Using an Intent? Or I don't understand your question

Comment: Activities are changed with Intents, but when you try out the Tinder app there is an animation when you move from one Activity to another. How can I do that?

Comment: Add an onClickListener to the image, which hides the button and shows the (hidden) text

Comment: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Shared-Element-Activity-Transition